# Second language learning and immersion among native speakers

Tags: second-lang-acquisition

In second language learning is there any evidence that fluency cannot be achieved without immersion among native language speakers?  If 'yes', what is the reason?

Comment: You can't prove a negative... and there's no universal definition of "fluency" ;)

Comment: Further, individual variables swamp everything else. Some people will become fluent despite barriers, while others will plateau out with much lower fluency.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the language acquisition, not about Linguistics itself. Being edited to make it more specific, it may fit at [languagelearning.se], however.